# How to get a length of the shown text in the label

Tags: c#, vb.net, string, winforms, label

I have a text with 1096 characters, and in the first page the label shown min 100 characters to 200 characters, click next button then remaining texts are shown in the same label(100 to 200 characters).

My question is how to get a shown text length when showing the first 100 or 200 texts. then only i can measure next characters to shown in the next page.

I did small sample code below.

```
string value = "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww"
                       + "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww" + "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww"
                       + "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww" + "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwww"
                       + "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww"
                       + "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww"
                       + "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww"
                       + "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww"
                       + "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww"
                       + "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww"
                       + "w                                                                                                          "
                       + "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww"
                       + "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww";
        this.label1.Text = value;
```

Label Shows only 168 character in first page.

[image]

When I click next page I need to show remaining text..

Comment: This is not simple to do, the TextRenderer.MeasureText() methods do not return the index of the last character that doesn't fit anymore.  You'd need to pinvoke DrawTextEx() so you can obtain the DRAWTEXTPARAMS.uiLengthDrawn value.  Pretty painful.  Not that much fun for the user either, they prefer a scrollbar of course.

Comment: @HansPassant : Thanks, But I am creating simulator for our device, So whatever in the device UI we need to do the same, So that I am doing this.

Comment: @HansPassant : Is it possible with custom Label in onpaintevent? if yes show me some example, Thanks